# array_slice throws undefined constant error

Tags: php

I am getting an array of ids from db, shuffling them and returning the first few elements:

```
    $stmt = $this->pdo->query("SELECT `id` FROM `IDS_TABLE` WHERE `active` = 1 LIMIT 10");
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if($rows){
        $pageIdsArray = array_map(function($page){return $page["id"];}, $rows);
        shuffle($pageIdsArray);
        error_log(json_encode($pageIdsArray)); // looks ok
        $result = array_slice($pageIdsArray, 0, 3); // error here
        return $result;
    }
```

To my suprise,this code throws: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: Use of undefined constant \xc2\xa00 - assumed '\xc2\xa00' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would try retyping that parameters on that line.

Comment: hmm, I am not getting it.  How would that help?

Comment: **tl;dr:** Unicode space issue. Protip for Vim users: I made a Vim plugin called [`vim-shitespace`](https://gitlab.com/h3xx/vim-shitespace) that highlights these characters among other problematic whitespace.

Comment: @sanjihan: For future reference: Such errors can be caught by looking at the error message. The "undefined constant" error message occurs when PHP suddenly finds literal text in the code while parsing the code (so not a string or variable name, but just characters written right there). The described string `\xc2\xa00` actually describes 3 bytes, two of which php escaped as hex (`\x`+2 hex digits), `\xc2` and `\xa0`, because php is not sure how/if to print them (unicode) and one regular ascii character: `0`. As the last character is `0`, the other 2 bytes (unicode char), must be left of `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two non-breaking space characters (u+00A0) before the `0` and the `3` in this line:

```
$result = array_slice($pageIdsArray, 0, 3); // error here
```

I'm guessing you may have copied this from a web page which inserted those characters for formatting.

Just retype it with regular spaces:

```
$result = array_slice($pageIdsArray, 0, 3);
```

For future reference, some IDEs/editors like VS Code can be configured to give you a warning if such characters are present:
[image]

Comment: Just came to the same conclusion. No idea about the 3, but for the 0 from the error message and looking up UTF-8 for the two hex-codes. +1

Comment: aaah. thank you. phpstorm did use different font and background color for the 0 and 3 now that you mention :)

Comment: @sanjihan: Does it answer as well your "How would that help?" question to Nigel Ren's comment? ^^

Comment: That is the UTF8 representation of that Unicode code point.

Comment: That question I can answer easily: \xC2\xA00 is UTF-8 encoding of U+00a0. Compare https://3v4l.org/GZqX8